# Global array list, jump to new index each time it's called

Tags: arrays, indexing, reset

So I have a global array list. Every time I call upon my hop method I want the code to go on to the next index of the array list. First time I call it, go to 303. Second time to 304, etc. When I've reached the last name I want the index to go back to 0. My code beneath here only keeps repeating the same one... what am I doing wrong?

```
int[] list = {303, 304, 305, 306, 309, 310, 311, 312, 313, 314, 317, 318, 319,
              320, 321, 322, 326, 327, 328, 329, 330, 334, 335, 336, 338, 341, 342, 343,
              344, 345, 346, 349, 350, 351, 352, 353, 354, 357, 358, 359, 360, 361, 362,
              366, 367, 368, 369, 370, 373, 374, 375, 376, 377, 378};

int index = 0;

public void hop() {

Game.hop(list[index]);
index =+ 1;

if(index > list.length) {

Index = list[0];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`index =+ 1;` needs to be `index += 1;` otherwise you're just setting the value to positive one each call